# Discord bot in python- message not sending

Tags: python, discord, bots

Below is the current code. I'm kinda new to python, but my previous bot with virtually the same code ran perfectly fine, so i don't understand why it's not running. The bot will turn on and show as "online" in Discord, but won't send the message.

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = 'token'

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    content = message.content
    user = message.author
    userid = message.author.id

    if content == "hello":
        await client.send_message(channel, "rude response")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Does it have the permission to post on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code to work you need to add a decorator to every method.

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = 'token'

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

# You forgot decorator here
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    content = message.content
    user = message.author
    userid = message.author.id

    if content == "hello":
        await client.send_message(channel, "rude response")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

`on_message` here is not decorated with `@client.event` hence you just define a function and never call it. Add the decorator to make a listener out of it

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
```